# How to iterate backwards through an OrderDictionary

Tags: c#, collections

I have an OrderedDictionary and I'm iterating through it like:

```
IDictionaryEnumerator myEnumerator = Model.RecentViews.GetEnumerator();

            while (myEnumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                <div>
                    <a href=@(myEnumerator.Key)>@myEnumerator.Value</a>
                </div>
            }
```

However I actually want to iterate through it in the reverse direction. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Basically I'm using this OrderedDictionary to display a list of links for the last visited pages on a site. The key is the url and the value is the text for the link. I'm trying to display the most recent at the top hence I want to iterate backwards. The reason I used an OrderedDictionary is because the order of the links must be preserved.

Maybe I'm not using the right kind of collection I'm not sure?

Comment: Can't you use the Linq extension method [Reverse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358497.aspx) ??

Comment: Do you only use this `Dictionary` for iterations or do you key into it somewhere else in your application? If not, perhaps you could reconsider using a `LinkedList<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` or a `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`?

Answer (score 0):

Does this do the trick?

```
    foreach(var key in Model.RecentViews.Keys.Cast<*TheTypeOfTheKey*>().Reverse())
    {
        <div>
            <a href=@(key)>@Model.RecentViews[key]</a>
        </div>
    }
```

**Edit:**

Demo of use of a generic SortedList (Console Application);

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SortedList<int, string> dict = new SortedList<int, string>();
        dict.Add(22, "Entry22");
        dict.Add(11, "Entry11");

        //forward
        Console.WriteLine("Forward:");
        foreach (var item in dict)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", item.Key, item.Value );
        }

        //backward
        Console.WriteLine("Backward:");
        foreach (var item in dict.Reverse())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", item.Key, item.Value );
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Forward:
11 : Entry11
22 : Entry22
Backward:
22 : Entry22
11 : Entry11
```

Comment: OrderedDictionary does not support Linq's Reverse() extension.

Comment: so its no IEnumerable<KeyValuePair>? ... sec

Comment: No, its DictionaryEntry. Check this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: no clue if that works... never used this ... i use a generic SortedList most of the time which does probably the same?

Comment: @SelvaTS replace *TheTypeOfTheKey* with whatever the key is ... string int whatever ...

Comment: But personally i would use a SortedList<TKey,TValue>... easier to use

Comment: SortedList automatically sorts the keys, orderedlist retains the order in which you put the keys. Sorting is a predefined manner of ordering, e.g. size or alphabetical order. Putting 5,2,52,1,6 (like a stack) has an order but doesnt look very sorted ;)